# How do I get only checked in code?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

When I create builds I want only checked in code to be included to the respective build, not my testing code, comments or unfinished features.

Do I have to [deploy a build](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181712(v=vs.110).aspx) server or is there any alternative to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you would have a working branch in your source code repository for the current feature set, and a build/deploy branch. Only merge to the build branch when code is ready to build. If you have to do a build and it isn't ready, don't merge.

You don't need a build server, unless you want to set up a regimen of nightly builds or for continuous integration.